# Comparação de >= e <= com strings

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho um campo no banco de dados que está no seguinte formato: **YYYYMM**

Usando procedure consigo pesquisar normalmente esses campos:

```
WHERE I.DT_INCL >= @inicio   
AND I.DT_INCL <= @final
```

Ao tentar passar a query pra linq retorna o seguinte erro: **Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'**

```
(from incorporacao in Incorporacao.FoundEntities
where incorporacao.DataInclusao >= inicio && incorporacao.DataInclusao <= final
select incorporacao).ToList();
```

Cheguei em duas possíveis soluções:

Criar um método que retorna um `DateTime` sempre colocando o dia fixo ou deixar o campo como inteiro.

Qual dessas duas soluções é a mais correta nesse contexto? O banco de dados é antigo e não posso modifica-lo.

Comment: O ideal é utilizar campos do tipo DateTime ou SmallDateTime no banco para fazer comparações. Ao utilizar Nvarchar ou Varchar para datas no banco de dados, corre o risco de encontrar algo que não seja uma data, aí podem ocorrer exceções.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu tenho um projeto aqui com um problema similar. Utilizo inteiros para armazenar uma representação de ano e mês no formato **YYYYMM** sem problemas. Dessa forma um inteiro que simula uma data mais recente sempre será maior que uma data mais antiga.

Comment: Amigo, utilize os campos de data para data, inteiros para números inteiros. Esta sua solução não fica conforme as boas práticas de programação.

Comment: a questão é que ele precisa de ano e mês, não a data completa, mas uma maneira de armazenar uma representação de ano e mês no formato YYYYMM. Para isso o int funciona muito bem.

Comment: Exato, peço desculpas por não ter entendido bem. Edite sua resposta para que eu possa votar a favor.

Comment: Sem problemas, valeu.

Answer (score 2):

Na stored o código irá ser executado pela engine do banco de dados. Ela tenta converter **String** em **Date**.

Em C# não existe isso, por isso você deve utilizar tipos de dados que sejam comparáveis. Sugiro que você faça a conversão das Strings em DateTime para utilizar na expressão LINQ.

Comment: Esta resposta é ideal caso a estrutura do banco não possa ser modificada. Programadores tendem a usar string para guardar datas por medo de usar Date ou DateTime, o ideal é usar a estrutura adequada para o tipo de dado.

Comment: Lembre-se que se você precisar converter os dados armazenados para poder filtra-los você precisará faze-lo em todos os dados da tabela, não é muito eficiente. O ideal é armazenar com os tipos corretos. Como un inteiro pode funcionar mas eu ainda usaria um tipo de data.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi acredito que você esteja em busca da solução mais legível. Nesse caso seria declarar o formato da data e fazer a comparação através do método `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
        string dateString1 = "201406";
        string dateString2 = "201407";
        string formatString = "yyyyMM";

        if (DateTime.ParseExact(dateString1, formatString, null) < DateTime.ParseExact(dateString2, formatString, null))
        {
            //Código...
        }
```

ps. O mais performático seria de fato a comparação dos inteiros.